# Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 android emulator invalid device

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

The android emulator in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 will not start. If I try to start a debug session with any native android c++ project on any android emulator (KitKat or Lollipop, phone or tablet) I'll get the error message:

```
"The device '' is invalid or not running.  Please switch to another device,  or use the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager to start a compatible emulator, or connect a compatible Android device."
```

I repaired and reinstalled Visual Studio and the Visual Studio android emulator already several times.

Comment: does it work if you use one of the Google emulators (it should automatically come up in the debug dropdown)? can you do a rebuild of the project and see if that fixes it? could you attach the entire error log, does that error come out of the deployment?

Comment: One strange thing is in an older version of Visual Studio 2015 preview I'll got a android VM in the Hyper-V Manager. This is not longer the case.

3>------ Deploy started: Project: UnitTests.Packaging, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
3>Starting emulator...
3>Error installing the package. The device '' is invalid or not running.  Please switch to another device, or use the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager to start a compatible emulator, or connect a compatible Android device.
3>The device is invalid or is not running.

Comment: Yes I can use the AVD's but I currently evaluating the features of Visual Studio 2015 and want to use the Visual Studio android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing a Hyper-V entry for the emulator.

It looks like you're using the CTP6 version of the Visual Studio Emulator for Android (which has support for KitKat and Lollipop).

The CTP6 version of the emulator requires the matching CTP6 version of Visual Studio 2015. The first thing to try is to install the CTP6 version of Visual Studio here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs.aspx

After installing VS CTP6, confirm that the version number of the emulator is still 1.0.50219.2 in Add Remove Programs (Control Panel).

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. The version number of the emulator is 1.0.50213.1. The version number of Visual Studio is 14.0.22609.0 D14REL. Both are installed from the same iso image I downloaded from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes sorry it is a CTP6 not CTP5 iso.